# Writing dynamic Redirect rule in Windows server web.config file

Tags: php, asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I am facing the problem of SEO canonical issues which I am trying to solve with web.config file. The same page is accessed on multiple URLs (2 specifically)

**My server is Windows-based but I am using PHP Codeigniter script.**

my URL structure is

```
https://example.com/xyz/index.php/dynamic-part/optional-dynamic-part
```

BUT
it is also accessible using

```
example.com/xyz/dynamic-part/optional-dynamic-part
```

What I want is

1. The only accessible link should be
   example.com/xyz/index.php/dynamic-part/optional-dynamic-part
2. if someone tries to access `https://example.com/xyz/dynamic-part/optional-dynamic-part` this way, he should be permanently redirected to `https://example.com/xyz/index.php/dynamic-part/optional-dynamic-part`

I have tried the following:

```
<rule name="redirecting" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="^ci/actionone*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="ci/index.php/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
```

Another attempt was:

```
<rule name="someRule" stopProcessing="true">
<match pattern="^ci" />
<<conditions>
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" type="Pattern" pattern="^index">
</<conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="example.com/ci/index.php/actionone" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>

<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
        <add key="/ci/actionone" value="/ci/index.php/actionone" />
        
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Please guide me how to fix this. Thank you

Comment: Is ci a fixed folder name? Does actionone in your rewrite rule represent one of the dynamic-parts? Maybe you can try changing the first rewrite rule to <match url="^ci/(.*)"/>. What was the result of your attempt? Are there any errors? If an error occurs, you can use FRT to trace the error page to find the cause of the error.

Comment: Yes, ci is the folder name. 
actionone is a URL endpoint that has some posts and pagination like actionone/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back again! with a solution that works for me

Here is the solution.

Basically what I did is check if the URL hits with a specific string *in my case* `ci/actionone` and have ANY string the URL will be redirected to the action URL.

```
<rule name="name1: with pagination">
    <match url="^(ci/actionone)/(.*)$"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="ci/index.php/actionone/{R:2}"/>
</rule>
```

Similarly, if the URL contains an exact string, it will redirect to the exact action URL

This is because the first page is accessed without pagination and the next page has a pagination slug in the URL.

```
<rule name="name2: without pagination">
    <match url="^(ci/actionone)$"/>
    <action type="Redirect" url="ci/index.php/actionone"/>
</rule>
```